# How to store user's running balance for each month?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm developing a kind of financial calculator with Yii2 and MySQL.
There is 'operations' table in my db for storing all transactions (incomes and costs) for all users. In the user's dashboard I want to display a running balance for the moment.

Table 'operations':

```
id | user_id | sum | date_created | date_picked
```

`date_created` is a column with timestamp of moment when user create new operation, and `date_picked` is the date user picked for this operation.

I know I could sum ALL transactions for user and display the result, but if there are huge amount of transactions there will be a large load for db. So I need to recommend the right way for storing transactions and balances.

I think I can create a table in which I will store user's balance for the each month and calculate running balance for the moment with these values. Is it a possible solution?

But if user decide to change value of one of previous' month transaction I need to recalculate balance for this month and for the next months? Is a right way or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query

```
SELECT SUM(sum) FROM operations where user_id = {id}
```

is enough. There will not be a lot of load to the DB if you are doing it only for one user. Let's say you have 1 million records for all users. This query should be fine in both in term of execution time and resources. We have a DB with millions and millions of transactions like this and this takes about 400ms and almost no resource usage.

You can create a table to store each user's balance, but it is not needed. It will most definitely work, but if I were you, I would stick with this. Of course, if you are having billions and billions of transactions, then you might consider doing this, but I doubt it will come to this.